# What to do if Baal Tefillah forgets Yaaleh ViYavoh and remembers during Sim Shalom?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, chazzan-prayer-leader, rosh-chodesh-new-month

A baal tefillah who forgets Yaaleh Viyavoh in his silent Shmoneh Esrei doesn't need to repeat Shmoneh Esrei, because he'll be yotzei with Chazaras HaShatz.

If an individual forgets Yaaleh ViYavoh in Shmoneh Esrei at Shacharis and remembers in the middle of Sim Shalom, he has to go back to Retzei and continue from there.

What if a Baal Tefillah forgets Yaaleh ViYavoh in Shmoneh Esrei on Rosh Chodesh and remembers in the middle of Sim Shalom?
His options are:

- Finish Shmoneh Esrei as is, but that might be improper because the silent Shmoneh Esrei he's in the middle of is invalid due to the omitted Yaaleh ViYavoh, and finishing might be a bracha livatala.
- Go back to Retzei, but that might be a Bracha Livatala because really he doesn't need to fix this Shmoneh Esrei, being that he has Chazaras HaShatz to rely on.

What should a  Baal Tefillah do in this instance?

Comment: Why doesn't he need to fix this shemone esrei? I don't understand. He needs to fix it so much that if he doesn't he has to say a whole nother one.

Comment: A baal tefillah will be yotzei his shmoneh esrei with chazaras hashatz, so he doesn't need to fix this shmoneh esrei in order to be yotzei @DoubleAA

Comment: By your logic he doesn't need to even say a first shemone esrei at all...

Comment: @DoubleAA By that logic he should never have to daven a silent Shmoneh Esrei, and yet we know that's not true. When he davens a shmoneh esrei on Rosh Chodesh without Yaaleh Viyavoh that shmoneh esrei is invalid, and as a bidieved we let the chazaras hashatz work

Comment: Ok, so since we know he's supposed to say a first shemone esrei, and I think you'll agree he's supposed to say it correctly, then we're back to my first comment.

Comment: @DoubleAA But in a case where he makes it through his whole Shmoneh Esrei he's not supposed to repeat Shmoneh Esrei an additional time. Doing so would be a bracha levatala, or 19 of them actually.  So by going back to Retzei in this Shmoneh Esrei, he might be making a bracha levatala

Comment: I've never heard that him repeating his silent shemone esrei before the repetition would be a bracha levatala. Can you source that? Seems clearly false. If it's not a tircha then indeed it's obvious he has to. If it is a tircha detzibbura (which is common) he can start the repetition right away even if he showed up late and missed the silent prayer entirely, relying on the public prayer for his private one.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not clear on what you mean...how would the shliach tzibbur show up late and not be able to daven the silent shmoneh esrei? I would assume he's been at the amud since at least Yishtabach, no?

Comment: That's the normal case. I'm pointing out the extreme case. Say 10 people pray together and don't know how to lead aloud, and then someone joins who does know, he starts straight with the repetition.

Answer (score 0):

In the Dirshu Mishnah Berura they bring the [Tehilla L’Dovid](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8002&st=&pgnum=110&hilite=) 126:4 that says the chazzan stops in the middle of the quiet Shemona Esrei and doesn’t finish, since he relies on the repetition.

The Biur Halacha in [124:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Biur_Halacha.124.10.1?lang=bi) seems to agree with this, as he says in a case of someone who is going to be yotzei with the chazzan, he should stop in middle of Shemona Esrei and not finish:

> ובכה"ג לכאורה מפסיק מיד ואינו גומר תפלתו כיון דרצונו לצאת בשמיעה מהש"ץ ממילא מה שגומר תפלתו הוי ברכה לבטלה.

Comment: This is talking about going back to the beginning not going back one bracha to retze!!!! The level of tircha is not at all comparable, and there he has nothing half done to finish since he's effectively starting over.

Comment: The beiur halacha is talking about a case where you can't go back (due to a 'minhag' to ignore the rule that you must go back), so you can't prove to our case where you can.